# Kendo UI Grid not loading data from datasource

Tags: kendo-ui, observable, kendo-grid

I am new on kendo UI framework. I am struggling with observable datasource with kendoGrid.
The problem is the table gets created but with empty data.
Here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/praveeny1986/Pf3TQ/5/

And the code :

```
var gridDataModel = kendo.data.Model.define({
fields: {
    "Product": {
        type: "string"
    },
    "Domain": {
        type: "string"
    },
    "PercentPlan": {
        type: "string"
    },
    "CWV": {
        type: "string"
    },
    "Target": {
        type: "string"
    },
    "Accuracy": {
        type: "string"
    }
}
});

var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({data: tabledata1});

var gridModel = kendo.observable({
    gridData: dataSource
});
kendo.bind($("#chart"),gridModel);
$("#chart").kendoGrid({
    scrollable:false,
dataSource:gridModel.get('gridData'),
    height:600,
    autoBind:true,
    columns:[
        {
            field: "Product",
            title: "Product"
        },
        {
            field: "Domain",
            title: "Sales Domain"
        },
        {
            field: "PercentPlan",
            title: "% to Plan"
        },
        {
            field: "CWV",
            title: "CWV"
        },
        {
            field: "Target",
            title: "Target"
        },
        {
            field: "Accuracy",
            title: "Accuracy"
        }]
});
var tabledata1 = [
{
    Product:"mobile",
    Domain:"SMARTPHONES-EAST",
    PercentPlan:"95",
    CWV:"160",
    Target:"200",
    Accuracy:"9"
},
{
    Product:"mobile",
    Domain:2,
    PercentPlan:"80",
    CWV:"160",
    Target:"200",
    Accuracy:"8.5"
},
{
    Product:"mobile",
    Domain:3,
    PercentPlan:"75",
    CWV:"150",
    Target:"200",
    Accuracy:"8"
},
{
    Product:"mobile",
    Domain:4,
    PercentPlan:"60",
    CWV:"120",
    Target:"200",
    Accuracy:"6"
},
{
    Product:"mobile",
    Domain:5,
    PercentPlan:"50",
    CWV:"150",
    Target:"300",
    Accuracy:"5"
}
];
```

Please suggest what i am doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your table data is undefined at the time that you create and bind the datasource.

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({data: tabledata1});
var tabledata1 = [ ... ];
```

Move the declaration of tabledata1 to before creating the datasource.
See this updated fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/nukefusion/Pf3TQ/7/